# How to find out if the coconut oil that I will buy from a supermarket is food and/or allergy safe

Tags: coconut, allergy

I want to buy some coconut oil, but I have not tried any coconut oil before, so I don't know which coconut oil can cause food poisoning if used for cooking. I am not a doctor, so I am wondering how it's possible for me to find out if the coconut oil (that I am going to buy) from a supermarket is harmful to me (I have some concerns about allergies control)?

Comment: kitty, welcome here at Seasoned Advice! You know the network, but it's always a good idea to check the [help] about what is on topic and what not. For here, health and nutrition are clearly off-topic. I have also seen your post on Lifehack, btw, and I still don't fully understand your question. Food safety and food poisoning (probably on topic) are something  ery different from allergies (usually off-topic). Would you clarify, please?

Comment: Are you or anyone you know allergic to coconut in any way? Or are you asking if there's a food-grade kind of coconut oil and a non food-grade kind and how to distinguish them?

Comment: If a question is off-topic, that's fine - we just put it on hold, that's it. We certainly don't suspend the OP! In this case, I think it's a bit unclear, as Stephie mentioned - if there's a substance you *know* you're allergic to, discussing what it will/won't be in is generally on-topic, but if you're worried about general health it's not.

Comment: EDITED, "bad for me" reeks of a health question. Food safety, or what nutrients, impurities or additives a food can contain, are on topic. The only on topic EFFECTS on you are that you'll like the taste, dislike the taste, or keel over dead or sick.

Comment: I doubt that anything off the shelf could cause food poisoning and still be sold. Of course, if treated improperly, anything can cause food poisoning. If it's about allergies, check with your doctor. Do not rely on some random people on the internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the question is off-topic, I'm not sure if I should be answering this. If not, I'll rely on those more experienced to edit or remove it.

If you have no known allergies to other nuts or seeds, coconut oil sold in the FOOD section of a supermarket is safe. If you have allergies to any nuts or seeds, then you'd need to check for labeling saying if it was processed and packed in a nut/seed-free facility to be safe.

On the other hand, if you're wondering if you might be allergic to coconut itself and you don't know, think back to other foods you're eaten. Coconut is in many foods and I'd be surprised if you haven't eaten it before. It's found in a host of different candies (even as small bits of crunchy toasted coconut), puddings, cookies, cakes and other baked goods. It's included in different curries; sometimes finely ground like flour or as coconut milk. I'm sure there are other foods but this gives you an idea.

If you simply don't know, you might try a *very* small amount of dried shredded coconut and wait 24 hours. Initially, allergic reactions are generally mild as a full allergic response normally takes 2, 3 or more exposures to cause a full allergic reaction. Perhaps keep something like Benadryl on hand. Mind you, this is what I'd do but please use caution. You may not feel like trying this.